# No scope is shown in Batarang

Tags: angularjs, batarang

I installed batarang from chrome store. Run a sample script. The html works fine. But batarang shows no scope. Please help me. Thanks. Chrome is the latest version.

screenshot (http://s16.postimg.org/hvy1cveqp/image.jpg)

Regards,

Comment: sorry, the link given in post is unclear. Please see this picture. (http://postimg.org/image/tzxjkj5mj/)

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angularjs-batarang/issues/207

Comment: From the issue given by Claies, batarang never work anymore. I tried 0.4.3. Not work also. I am giving up using batarang now.

Answer (score 1):

Angular Batarang needs debug info to be enabled.

Run the following in console after loading website:

```
angular.reloadWithDebugInfo();
```

or set debug info enabled in app config:

```
myApp.config(['$compileProvider', function ($compileProvider) {
  $compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled(true);
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Batarang is RIP.
The last release of Batarang was over 10 months ago. It looks like it is no longer supported and does not work with Angular 1.2.x

**Update**

Still you can check [Angular Stable Batarang.](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang-stable/niopocochgahfkiccpjmmpchncjoapek?hl=en-US)

Comment: Thank you for your answer.<br/>1. I am using angular 1.0.2 (http://postimg.org/image/ba60n5ttn/).<br/>2. Angular Stable Batarang still not works. (http://postimg.org/image/lhwd555xp/)

Answer (score 0):

From the [issue link](http://github.com/angular/angularjs-batarang/issues/207) given by Claies, batarang never work anymore. As the thread asked, I tried 0.4.3. Not work also. I am giving up using batarang now. Thank you for everyone helping.